# Remote login impossible (SSH, web interface), console logs out immediatly after login

Tags: ssh, login

since some time I have this problem that (at irregular intervals) I can not log on to my server anymore. An SSH connection or web interface login just fails to login. Logging in on console works, but immediately after login I get logged out again.

Server runs Ubuntu Server 16.04.2 (LTS) with all the latest updates.

When I try to log in via SSH, I get the following error:

```
$ ssh wouter@Hyperion
wouter@Hyperion's password:
shell request failed on channel 0
```

After I force a restart of the server, everything works again for a while.

I found the following in /var/log/syslog, which corresponds with one of my failed login attempts:

```
May 25 12:43:16 Hyperion systemd[1]: Created slice User Slice of wouter.
May 25 12:43:16 Hyperion systemd[1]: Started Session 202 of user wouter.
May 25 12:43:16 Hyperion systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 1000...
May 25 12:43:16 Hyperion systemd[11198]: user@1000.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /lib/systemd/systemd: Resource temporarily unavailable
May 25 12:43:16 Hyperion systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 1000.
May 25 12:43:16 Hyperion console-kit-daemon[8174]: (process:11208): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
May 25 12:43:16 Hyperion console-kit-daemon[8174]: missing action
May 25 12:43:18 Hyperion console-kit-daemon[8174]: (process:11344): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
May 25 12:43:18 Hyperion console-kit-daemon[8174]: missing action
May 25 12:43:18 Hyperion console-kit-daemon[8174]: console-kit-daemon[8174]: GLib-CRITICAL: Source ID 87 was not found when attempting to remove it
May 25 12:43:18 Hyperion console-kit-daemon[8174]: GLib-CRITICAL: Source ID 87 was not found when attempting to remove it
May 25 12:43:18 Hyperion systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 1000.
May 25 12:43:18 Hyperion systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of wouter.
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Systemd looks broken. I would give and restart the server.

Comment: The problem is that the only way to reboot the server (that I know of) is the reset button, as I can't login (and stay logged in). Unless you know of a way to reboot it via a Samba share (that one keeps working...)